# dynamic vector of vectors of pointers to objects, C++

Tags: c++, class, vector

I would like to make a dynamic vector that consists of vectors of pointers (i.e. be able to add and remove vectors from the -bigger- vector at different moments in time). Would it be possible / a good idea to make a class that generates vectors as objects?

Comment: Yes, but leave the pointers part out.

Comment: std::vector<std::vector<MyClass>> or std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>>

Comment: If you tell us the purpose of creating the vectors we can help you better, maybe your original idea is not the direction to go

Comment: I'm trying to simulate groups of people walking towards a destination. These groups will start walking according to a poisson process (so they arrive at the scene at different times). Once a person has reached its destination, I want to remove the person.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to do what you want (see cppguy's comment).

However, in my opinion, it would be a good idea to create a Group class that contains a vector of Person class, and a Population class to manage the groups. E.g. :

```
class Person
{
public:
   Person();
   ~Person();
   void Update(double timeDifference);
   bool ShouldRemove();
   // whatever else you need in here
};

class Group
{
public:
   Group(int size);
   ~Group();
   void Update(double timeDifference);
   bool ShouldRemove();
private:
   std::vector<Person> m_people;
};

class Population
{
public:
   Population();
   ~Population();
   void AddGroup(int size);
   void Update(double timeDifference);
private:
   std::vector<Group> m_groups;
};
```

This should make updating the individual people and managing the adding/deleting of groups easier.